# Adobe Dreamweaver License in Ubuntu

Tags: commercial

Does Adobe DreamweaverCS5 running in Ubuntu require a License activation or not?

Comment: If it usually does, then it does so on Wine as well.

Answer (score 3):

You can't install anything from the Adobe Suite (including Dreamweaver) in Ubuntu (or any other Linux-based OS).

But you can do this with Wine/Play on Linux. And in that case CS5 is indeed the latest compatible version.
If you install something via Wine, the program will just think it's on a Windows system, so to answer your question;

Yes, then you also need a license.